# Adding new Entity data when user register in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
 {
     returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
     ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         var user = CreateUser();

         await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
         await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
         var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

         if (result.Succeeded)
         {
             _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
             // add SUPERADMIN role to the user

             await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "SuperAdmin");

             *var prof = new FakeProfile();
             prof.Name = Input.Name;
             prof.UserId = user.Id;
             prof.User = user;*
```

I have created a new FakerProfile Entity which user will have by default but user can add new profiles whenever thy want.
Here i want to add this info when user first register to the application But i am not able to add that since Identity doesn't have DBContext and I can't seem to find a way for it. How do i do that?
How do i access DbContext and add data for another Entity here?

Note: I just want to add new data here because i want to add it during the registration process. I don't want to place this logic on another screen or add this data to the Existing Entities

here is my Context:

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyContext (DbContextOptions<MyContext > options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<FakeProfile> FakeProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `FakeProfile` is a part of your `DbContext`?

Comment: @AmitMohanty I have updated the details and added MyContext. I'm new to the .net realm by the way so...

Comment: The problem is that i can't access MyContext in the method so I can't save my changes from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have a constructor in your page model to receive the `MyContext`.

```
public class YourPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public YourPageModel(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // ... other code
}
```

Then, within your `OnPostAsync` method, you can create a `FakeProfile` instance and add it to the context.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = CreateUser();

        await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
            // add SUPERADMIN role to the user

            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "SuperAdmin");

            var prof = new FakeProfile();
            prof.Name = Input.Name;
            prof.UserId = user.Id;
            prof.User = user;

            _context.FakeProfiles.Add(prof);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But  I'm using the register.cshtml page which is provided by the Identity Scaffolding. I tried to change it but its not able to access it

Answer (score 0):

```
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

public RegisterModel(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore,
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
    ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
    IEmailSender emailSender,
    MyDbContext dbContext
    )
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _userStore = userStore;
    _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _logger = logger;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
    _dbContext = dbContext;
```

}